# Group by and conditionals

Tags: pandas, dataframe, if-statement, conditional-statements, where-clause

## I want to clasify

| Nombre | Class | TOTAL | COST Cost |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Biotechnology Discovery | A | 1.82% | 0.75% |
| Biotechnology Discovery | C | 2.40% | 1.00% |
| Biotechnology Discovery | N | 2.57% | 1.25% |
| Biotechnology Discovery | I | 1.15% | 0.00% |
| Global Growth | A | 1.89% | 0.75% |
| Global Growth | N | 2.64% | 1.25% |
| Global Growth | I | 1.15% | 0.00% |

## WITHIN EACH 'NOMBRE'

## if cost equals 0  INSTITUCIONAL

## if cost min  barata

## if cost is > min  cara

## if cost is max  super cara

| Nombre | Class | TOTAL | COST Cost |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Biotechnology Discovery | A | 1.82% | 0.75% |
| Biotechnology Discovery | C | 2.40% | 1.00% |
| Biotechnology Discovery | N | 2.57% | 1.25% |
| Biotechnology Discovery | I | 1.15% | 0.00% |
| Global Growth | A | 1.89% | 0.75% |
| Global Growth | N | 2.64% | 1.25% |
| Global Growth | I | 1.15% | 0.00% |

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in a series of steps that performs filtering directly. First, initialize your label as "cara." This represents all of your values between min and max. From there, we just need to find your zero, min, and max values.

```
# Convert percent to a number
df['COST num'] = df['COST Cost'].str.slice(0,4).astype('float64')

# Initialize the label to 'cara.' This represents all the in-between values.
df['label'] = 'cara'

# Set 0 to INSTITUCIONAL
df.loc[df['COST num'] == 0, 'label'] = 'INSTITUCIONAL'

# Get min value where cost is not 0
df.loc[df[df['COST num'] > 0].groupby('Nombre')['COST num'].idxmin(), 'label'] = 'barata'

# Get max value
df.loc[df.groupby('Nombre')['COST num'].idxmax(), 'label'] = 'super cara'

# Remove the converted value
df = df.drop('COST num', axis=1)
```

```
                    Nombre Class  TOTAL COST Cost          label
0  Biotechnology Discovery     A  1.82%     0.75%         barata
1  Biotechnology Discovery     C  2.40%     1.00%           cara
2  Biotechnology Discovery     N  2.57%     1.25%     super cara
3  Biotechnology Discovery     I  1.15%     0.00%  INSTITUCIONAL
4            Global Growth     A  1.89%     0.75%         barata
5            Global Growth     N  2.64%     1.25%     super cara
6            Global Growth     I  1.15%     0.00%  INSTITUCIONAL
```